FloatingActionButton not displaying Flutter
I am creating a FloatingActionButton inside the Scaffold widget, but it is not visible and clickable. There is no error in the console and the body section of the scaffold is visible. The background color of the FAB is green, the icon color is black, and the scaffold color is white, so I believe it is not due to color contrast.

I resolved the issue by making extendBody: false(default is false) inside my Home Scaffold(which is responsible for bottomnavbar). If true, and bottomNavigationBar or persistentFooterButtons is specified, then the body extends to the bottom of the Scaffold, instead of only extending to the top of the bottomNavigationBar or the persistentFooterButtons. Thank you everyone.

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: const Center(child: Text("Hello Products")),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: KColors.primary,
            onPressed: (){KLoggerHelper.debug("FAB is here");},
            child: const Icon(Iconsax.add, color: KColors.black),
          ),
        );
      }

My Flutter Version is
Flutter 3.24.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5874a72aa4 (5 weeks ago) • 2024-08-20 16:46:00 -0500
Engine • revision c9b9d5780d
Tools • Dart 3.5.1 • DevTools 2.37.2

I tried changing the color contrast but it did not work.
I tried downgrading the Flutter version but it did not work.


Can you share a reference screenshot to understand the situation

heyy @AkhilSuthapalli I have added a screenshot in the question. Thank you.

Can't see any bottomNavBar in code-snippet but have in image

To resolve the FloatingActionButton display issue:

Add AppBar to the Scaffold:
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Your App Title'),
  ),
  // ... other Scaffold properties
)


Use SingleChildScrollView in the Scaffold body:
Scaffold(
  // ... appBar and other properties
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        // Your content widgets here
      ],
    ),
  ),
)




To address the issue of the FloatingActionButton (FAB) not being visible or clickable, despite no errors in the console and proper color contrast, one possible cause is indeed the usage of the Iconsax package for the icon.
Here's a breakdown of what could be happening:
Iconsax Compatibility: The Iconsax package is a third-party package, and there's a chance that the Iconsax.add icon might not be rendering correctly in the FloatingActionButton. While the body section is visible, the FAB might not appear if the icon fails to load or is incompatible with the current Flutter version (Flutter 3.24.1 in this case).
Troubleshooting the Icon: Since the FAB itself is not showing or responding, and the only custom element within the button is the Iconsax.add, it's worth verifying if the icon renders properly in other widgets. Try using a default Flutter icon (like Icons.add) to check if the FAB appears and works as expected:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: const Center(child: Text("Hello Products")),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      backgroundColor: KColors.primary,
      onPressed: () {
        KLoggerHelper.debug("FAB is here");
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: KColors.black),
    ),
  );
}

If the FAB shows up with the default Icons.add, this indicates that the issue lies with the Iconsax.add icon, either due to a rendering issue, missing dependency, or compatibility problem.
Verifying Iconsax Package:
Ensure that the Iconsax package is properly included in your pubspec.yaml file and that the correct version is installed.
If the package is correctly configured, try using other icons from Iconsax to check if the problem is isolated to the add icon or affects other icons as well.
If other Iconsax icons also don't render, it may suggest a package compatibility issue with your current Flutter version (3.24.1). You can check the package documentation and repository for any known issues related to your Flutter version.
Alternative Approach: If you confirm the issue is with Iconsax, consider filing a bug report on the package's GitHub repository or using another reliable icon package (like FontAwesome or Material Icons) until the issue is resolved.
